# Serilization Operations

Tags: java, serialization

I want to print list of data in file

```
List<TimeSheetVO> timesheetlist;
            java.sql.Date dbdateformat = null;

            String date="2013-02-06";              

                timesheetlist=new ArrayList<TimeSheetVO>();


               java.sql.Date dbdate=java.sql.Date.valueOf(date);        
                try{
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.101:3306/bio_tracker_eden","eden","centris");
                    String query = "select * from ai_bio_timesheet where ATTENDANCE_DATE=?";
                    PreparedStatement   psmt=con.prepareStatement(query);
                    psmt.setDate(1,dbdate );
                    ResultSet rs=psmt.executeQuery();
                    while(rs.next())
                    {
                         timeSheetVO =new TimeSheetVO();

                        timeSheetVO.setEMP_ID(rs.getString("EMP_ID"));
                        timeSheetVO.setATTENDANCE_DATE(rs.getString("ATTENDANCE_DATE"));
                        timeSheetVO.setIN_TIME(rs.getTime("IN_TIME"));
                        timeSheetVO.setOUT_TIME(rs.getTime("OUT_TIME"));


                        timesheetlist.add(timeSheetVO);
                        File file=new File("D:/timesheet.txt");
                        ObjectOutputStream outstream=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
                        outstream.writeObject(timesheetlist);
                        outstream.flush();
                        outstream.close();
                    }


                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
```

Here I retrieve the data from database and store the data into list and that list is stored in to file.
But the file is not stored the values.
Can you explain where the problem is?
Here values are coming from database but not displayed in file
I use the below class:

```
public class TimeSheetVO implements Serializable{


    private String EMP_ID;
    private String ATTENDANCE_DATE;
    private Time IN_TIME;
    private Time OUT_TIME;
    private Time TOTAL_HOURS;

    public String getEMP_ID() {
        return EMP_ID;
    }
    public void setEMP_ID(String eMP_ID) {
        EMP_ID = eMP_ID;
    }

    public String getATTENDANCE_DATE() {
        return ATTENDANCE_DATE;
    }
    public void setATTENDANCE_DATE(String aTTENDANCE_DATE) {
        ATTENDANCE_DATE = aTTENDANCE_DATE;
    }
    public Time getIN_TIME() {
        return IN_TIME;
    }
    public void setIN_TIME(Time iN_TIME) {
        IN_TIME = iN_TIME;
    }
    public Time getOUT_TIME() {
        return OUT_TIME;
    }
    public void setOUT_TIME(Time oUT_TIME) {
        OUT_TIME = oUT_TIME;
    }
    public Time getTOTAL_HOURS() {
        return TOTAL_HOURS;
    }
    public void setTOTAL_HOURS(Time tOTAL_HOURS) {
        TOTAL_HOURS = tOTAL_HOURS;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return new StringBuffer().append(EMP_ID).
                append("\n").
                append(ATTENDANCE_DATE).
                append("\n").
                append(IN_TIME).
                append("\n").
                append(OUT_TIME).toString();
    }


}
```

Here printing the values in file:
[72013-02-0617:50:1519:19:15
, 132013-02-0619:02:1119:02:25
, 212013-02-0618:25:2218:25:22
, 282013-02-0618:25:4318:25:43
, 442013-02-0619:20:2019:41:21
, 562013-02-0617:54:0817:54:08
]

But I want to print like this:
72013-02-0617:50:1519:19:15
132013-02-0619:02:1119:02:25
212013-02-0618:25:2218:25:22
282013-02-0618:25:4318:25:43
442013-02-0619:20:2019:41:21
562013-02-0617:54:0817:54:08
Here am append  \n but new line is not coming

Comment: 1.does `select` return values? 2. Does the empty "temsheet.txt" get created? 3.TimeSheetVO is Serializable?

Comment: Why are you storing the list. You can directly store TimeSheetVO instance as it is serializable?

Comment: Can you put serialization code outside while loop? I have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your serialization works fine, I tested locally, you should be able to re create List of TimeSheetVO by doing deserialization.

> Primary purpose of java serialization is to write an object into a
>   stream, so that it can be transported through a network and that
>   object can be rebuilt again

If you want write the only content of the object in to file, then you would not require serialization, rather write obj.data as plain text in to file.

**--- EDIT--**

Can you put `serialization` code outside `while loop`?

```
    while(rs.next())
    {
        timeSheetVO =new TimeSheetVO();

        timeSheetVO.setEMP_ID(rs.getString("EMP_ID"));
        timeSheetVO.setATTENDANCE_DATE(rs.getString("ATTENDANCE_DATE"));
        timeSheetVO.setIN_TIME(rs.getTime("IN_TIME"));
        timeSheetVO.setOUT_TIME(rs.getTime("OUT_TIME"));
        timesheetlist.add(timeSheetVO);
    }
    File file=new File("D:/timesheet.txt");
    ObjectOutputStream outstream=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    outstream.writeObject(timesheetlist);
    outstream.flush();
    outstream.close();
```